# Experience Manager on load balanced environment

Tags: experience-manager

There is a specific requirement to setup Experience Manager on a load balanced environment.

On the Content Delivery side, not sure about how to configure the Session Preview webservice on both servers what what could be the complexities involved which need to take care of, in advance.

Comment: What problems are you encountering? I can't see any immediately obvious reasons why this would be any different to a normal XPM setup.

Comment: You will probably need sticky sessions, so you end up on the sever that has the correct temporary files created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The architecture of XPM is such that part of it is within your website build (ADF), part is the Session Preview Web Service, part is a dependency on the Content Manager, and, of course, the underlying databases (CM DB, Broker DB and the Session Preview DB).

So if you need to scale it out, you'll need to consider all these parts.  Think through why you're scaling out: fail over, high availability performance or all), and scale out what you need (based on content editors'/users' actions). If doing a lot if previewing, then reinforce your Preview Webservice and DB (as per the documentation Eric provided links to).  If doing a lot of saving of pages and components, then look  the CM servers.

Comment: I am already done with the other configuration of XPM like CM, DB setups. On the content delivery front, i am pretty much comfortable with XPM CD setup on single server, however, not sure about the efforts needed on load balanced environment side. I followed the links Eric have provided but that too **lack information for XPM session preview webservice setup on load balanced env.**

Comment: The Session Preview web service is just another J2EE web app.  So scaling it out is done by following the standard practices of scaling out any Java web app: stick your instances behind a load balancer, point the website instances' configs to the load balanced web service url and you should be good to go (oh, and you might need to enable Sticky Sessions on the LB).  [P.S. don't forget to play the stackexchange game and upvote]

Comment: Slight correction to my comment above.  The web service is available in .NET as well (wrapping the Java implementation), but the scaling out procedure would be similar for any technology.

Answer (score 4):

Experience Manager is a complex application that has several pieces that can be scaled.

1. Web Application: [Scaling Content Delivery](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-A3E4D814-B887-4C59-B2E4-CE405ED2DF32&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-A3E4D814-B887-4C59-B2E4-CE405ED2DF32.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A3E4D814-B887-4C59-B2E4-CE405ED2DF32&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US&action=search&query=Scale%2520Content%2520Delivery&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1391601827648&currentQuery=Scale%2520Content%2520Delivery&currentScope=) Login is required
2. Content Manager: [Scaling Content Manager](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-5570B671-C4CD-4CC9-943B-489E5390C13E&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-5570B671-C4CD-4CC9-943B-489E5390C13E.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-5570B671-C4CD-4CC9-943B-489E5390C13E&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Tridion+full+documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DScaling%2520Content%2520Delivery%2520Web%2520Service&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1391601894250&currentQuery=Scaling%2520Content%2520Delivery%2520Web%2520Service&currentScope=) Login is required
3. Content Delivery Web Service: You need to scale a the REST Web Service.

You will need to identify which parts need to be scaled.

**UPDATE**
I would recommend considering the usage of Sticky Sessions. It is related to the fact that not all the ADF objects are serializable (ClaimStore) causing issues if you want to scale your session data storage.